# Not able to load image to PDF using jspdf

Tags: jspdf

I'm trying to load image into PDF using jspdf javascript library.I can successfully get  data of image however output PDF is not showing any image.

Below is complete code snippet.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf/base64.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf/sprintf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf/jspdf.js"></script>


 var createPDF = function(imgData) {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    alert("before create pdf ::::"); 
    doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 500, 500);
    //doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 70, 10, 100, 120);

    // Output as Data URI
    doc.output('datauri');
 }




  var darthImgData;
  function childCanvas()
  {
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var imageObj = new Image();

      imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 69, 50);
        darthImgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').slice('data:image/jpeg;base64,'.length);
        // Convert the data to binary form
        darthImgData = atob(darthImgData);
        alert(darthImgData);
        createPDF(darthImgData);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'thinking-monkey.jpg';


  }
```

Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last, I found the solution for above said issue.JSPDF team added javascript plugin for adding image in generated PDF files in client-side JavaScript.

I've added below jspdf scripts in my code, was able to generate PDF with image.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf/jspdf.plugin.addimage.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you use the jspdf.source.js file I'm pretty sure the libraries are all included.

Comment: Where to put this?